# Entity Framework Query to prefer a certain field value, if not select first or default

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL Server table with fields as below

```
Table name: Dashboard
Fields: Id, OwnerId, DashboardName, CreatedDate
```

How do I write a single Entity Framework query (don't want to hit database twice) to get a dashboard that matches a given OwnerId and a preferred DashboardName? If that DashboardName is not matched, I want the Dashboard with earliest CreatedDate to be returned.

The equivalent sql for which I need the EF QUERY will be probably look like

```
 select *,  1 as preference from Dashboard OwnerId=1 and DashboardName = 
 'my dashboard'
 union 
 select *, 2 as preference from Dashboard where OwnerId=1 
 order by preference, CreatedDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ternary conditional operator in LINQ / EF.

```
var dashboard = (from d in db.Dashboard
                 where d.OwnerId == 1
                 select new { d, pref = (d.DashboardName == "my dashboard") ? 1 : 2 }
                 orderby pref, d.CreatedDate
                ).FirstOrDefault().d;
```